# C++ for-loop structure with multiple variable initialization

Tags: c++, for-loop

On the 2nd for-loop, I get the following error from gcc:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before 'int'
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing. I've looked over documentation for how a for-loop should look and I'm still confused. What's wrong here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() { 
std::vector<int> values; 

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) { 
  values.push_back(i); 
}   

std::cout << "Reading values from 'std::vector values'" << std::endl;
for (int i = 0, int col = 0; i < values.size(); i++, col++) {
  if (col > 10) { std::cout << std::endl; col == 0; }
  std::endl << values[i] << ' ';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try without the `int` before `col`.

`for (int i = 0, col = 0; i < values.size(); i++, col++)`

Comment: Thank you - I didn't notice this at all.

Comment: Can we perform logical operation between the two conditions pertaining to the variables `i` and `j`  in placeholder for condition in the `for` loop?

Answer (score 7):

Others have already told you how to fix the problem you've noticed. On a rather different note, in this:

```
if (col > 10) { std::cout << std::endl; col == 0; }
```

It seems nearly certain that the last statement here: `col==0;` is really intended to be `col=0;`.

Comment: That would be true - this was a simple test case I put together for the question. Good catch

Answer (score 3):

This should fix it

```
for (int i = 0, col = 0; i < values.size(); i++, col++) {
  if (col > 10) { std::cout << std::endl; col == 0; }
  std::endl << values[i] << ' ';
  }
}
```

A variable definition goes like this

datatype variable_name[=init_value][,variable_name[=init_value]]*;

Comment: The last sentence is not really true.  For example, the following is valid:  `int w, *x, (*y)(int, int), z;`

Comment: I agree! I couldn't find the c++ standards' definition of variable declaration. Hence have given an abstract representation of a var declaration. here variable name doesn't strictly confirm to [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*. It can also mean *x, e.g. int w = 10, *x = NULL; Thanks for clarifying ! :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't declare int after comma use,

```
for (int i = 0,col = 0; i < values.size(); i++, col++) {
  if (col > 10) { std::cout << std::endl; col == 0; }
  std::endl << values[i] << ' ';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is akin to a regular multiple variables declaration/initialization in one line using a comma operator. You can do this:

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
```

declaring 2 ints. But not this:

```
int a = 1, int b = 2;   //ERROR
```